# Solve 6th degree polynomial: $(x^2 - 3x - 4)(x^2 - 5x + 6)(x^2 + 2x) + 30$

Tags: polynomials

I came across what seems to be a very difficult "solve for $x$" type of
problem, primarily because there should be $6$ real roots of this problem:
$$(x^2 - 3x - 4)(x^2 - 5x + 6)(x^2 + 2x) + 30 = 0.$$
My first step was to (tediously) expand this into the degree $6$ polynomial
that it is:
$$x^6-6 x^5+x^4+36 x^3-20 x^2-48 x+30 = 0.$$
I would imagine that the first step would be to simplify this into a set of
smaller roots, i.e.
$$(ax + b)(cx^5 + dx^4 + ex^3 + fx^2 + gx + h) = 0,$$
and then perform a similar factorization on the polynomial of degree $5$.
However, after trying hard to find the constant terms for this factorization,
I can never quite get the correct factorization. Any recommendations on
problems like these? I would really like to solve this without using Wolfram.

Comment: if there is any chance of this being solved by hand, it means that the revised polynomial factors nicely into into linear terms and quadratics.

Comment: This factors as $(x^2-2x-5)(x^4-4x^3-2x^2+12x-6)=0$, and no further over the integers.  Four of the six roots come from the quartic, and aren't particularly nice.

Comment: @vadim123 What's not particularly nice about $1 \pm \sqrt{6}/2 \pm \sqrt{10}/2$?

Comment: @vadim123 The quartic can be rewritten as the biquadratic $(x-1)^4 - 8 (x-1)^2 + 1$ but that's not quite obvious to guess.

Comment: Here's a method that does not require any "tricks".  When you solve a quartic equation by the general method, look for a rational root of the resolvent cubic.  If this exists, the roots will take a simplified form.

Comment: Can't we do anything with the obvious factorization $(x^2−3x−4)(x^2−5x+6)(x^2+2x) = -30$ hence$(x+1)(x-4)(x-3)(x-2)(x)(x+2) = -30$? EDIT: oops I just saw stewbasic did that, and reduced it to a cubic in $(x-1)^2$

Comment: Tip: the resulted number-only value (with no x) is the key. You spit that into the numbers you need for the high factor elements.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Let $P(x)$ denote the LHS. Note that the first summand factors nicely:
$$
  P(x)=(x-2)(x-3)(x-4)x(x+1)(x+2)+30.
$$
From this it is clear that $P(x)$ is symmetric around $x=1$. Explicitly, setting $y=x-1$ we have
$$\begin{eqnarray*}
  P(x)&=&(y-1)(y-2)(y-3)(y+1)(y+2)(y+3)+30\\
    &=&(y^2-1)(y^2-4)(y^2-9)+30.
\end{eqnarray*}$$
Note that this is a cubic in $y^2$, so it is possible to solve for $y^2$ using the [formula for roots of a cubic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function#General_formula), and hence find the roots of $P$ in terms of radicals.

Comment: Nice. And the cubic (in $y^2$) does actually have an easy to find rational root, which leaves a plain quadratic.

Comment: dammit I almost noticed the symmetry when was looking for a solution myself.

Comment: This is a beautiful use of symmetry ! And, since there is a very simple root for the cubic in $y^2$, the solutions are quite nice (if one enjoys radicals). Thanks for this answer.

Answer (score 2):

Your $6$'th degree polynomial does not have any rational roots (which you could show using the Rational Roots Theorem).  It turns out to have a quadratic factor
$x^2-2x-5$.  It factors completely into factors of the form $x - (a + b \sqrt{6} + c \sqrt{10})$ with $a$, $b$, $c$ rational, but I don't see how you could guess that "by hand".